# How to inflate dynamically generated relative layout to Listview rows?

Tags: android

I have dynamically created a relative layout containing textview and radiobutton dynamically.now i need to inflate this layout in to listview rows.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    txt = new TextView(context);
    txt.setId(1001);
    txt.setText("Question");
    txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txt.setTextSize(5);
    txt.setLayoutParams(params);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams quesParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    quesParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1001);
    quesParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    TextView txtQues = new TextView(context);
    txtQues.setId(1010);
    txtQues.setText("What is the oldest civilization on earth?");
    txtQues.setTextSize(10);
    txtQues.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    txtQues.setLayoutParams(quesParams);
    RadioButton rdp = new RadioButton(context);
    rdp.setText("Harrapa");
    rdp.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    rdp.setTextSize(10);
    RadioButton rd2 = new RadioButton(context);
    rd2.setText("Egypt");
    rd2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    rd2.setTextSize(10);
    RadioButton rd3 = new RadioButton(context);
    rd3.setText("Egypt");
    rd3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    rd3.setTextSize(10);
    RadioButton rd4 = new RadioButton(context);
    rd4.setText("kumarikandam");
    rd4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    rd4.setTextSize(10);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams radioGrpparms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    radioGrpparms.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    radioGrpparms.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1010);

    rdgrp = new RadioGroup(context);
    rdgrp.setLayoutParams(radioGrpparms);
    rdgrp.addView(rdp, radioGrpparms);
    rdgrp.addView(rd2, radioGrpparms);
    rdgrp.addView(rd4, radioGrpparms);

    RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(context);
    rel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    rel.addView(txt);
    rel.addView(txtQues);
    rel.addView(rdgrp);
    rel.setId(1050);
    //setContentView(rel);

    rdgrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton view=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
            Toast.makeText(context,view.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Need to a populate this dynamically generated relative layout to listview rows

Comment: http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/8/Creating-Android-button-with-image-and-text-using-relative-layout.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add your code to the `getView()` method of the `ListView` `Adapter`